# Leer valores de celda excel como bool()

Tags: python, openpyxl

No consigo entender el funcionamiento del tipo bool() en Python.

Estoy leyendo un hoja excel, en ella tengo celdas con textos:

| celda | valor |
| --- | --- |
| D60 | true |
| D62 | false |

Quiero asignar los valores ledos como tipo bool(), mi idea era hacer:

```
x1 = bool(sh['D60'].value.capitalize()) #el valor en el excel esta en minúsculas y python bool() se define con mayúscula inicial
x2 = bool(sh['D62'].value.capitalize())
```

Pero los valores se no se almacenan correctamente...

```
x1 = bool(sh['D60'].value.capitalize())
x1
True
x2 = bool(sh['D62'].value.capitalize())
x2
True
```

He probado con in print() previo pero tampoco...

```
x1 = bool(print(sh['D60'].value.capitalize()))
True
x1
False
x2 = bool(print(sh['D62'].value.capitalize()))
False
x2
False
```

Como se puede hacer esto correctamente en una sola linea?
Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando usas `bool()` alrededor de un valor, Python usa una de las siguientes reglas:

- Si el valor es entero, entonces saldrá `False` si era 0, y `True` si era distinto de cero.
- Si el valor es una cadena, entonces saldrá `False` si la cadena era `""` (cadena vacía) y `True` si era distinta de `""`
- Si el valor es una lista, entonces saldrá `False` si la lista está vacía, y `True` si tiene algún elemento
- Si el valor es un diccionario, entonces saldrá `False` si el diccionario está vacío y `True` si tiene algún elemento.
- Si es un objeto (una instancia de una clase), llamará a la función `objeto.__bool__()` y el resultado será `True` o `False`, según lo que esa llamada retorne (eso te permite implementar tus propias clases con sus propias reglas de cómo convertirse a booleano).
- Si el valor es `None` el resultado es siempre `False`.

En tu caso, por desgracia, lo que lees de la Excel es una cadena. La cadena vale `"true"` o `"false"`, pero de acuerdo con la segunda regla antes vista, ambas darán como resultado `True`, ya que ambas **son diferentes a la cadena vacía**.

Cuando metes un print por el medio, `bool(print(loquesea))`, estás aplicando `bool()` al resultado devuelto por `print()`. El resultado devuelto no tiene nada qué ver con lo que se imprima, sino con lo que `print()` tenga en su `return` (si tiene uno). En el caso de `print()` se retorna `None`, por lo que estás convirtiendo `None` a booleano y como vimos, eso siempre sale `False`.

La solución por tanto será implementar tu propia función que devuelva `True` si la cadena que le pasas contiene `"true"`, o `False` si contiene `"false"`.

Sería así:

```
def my_bool(cadena):
   if cadena.lower() == "true":
       return True
   else:
       return False
```

O de forma más compacta:

```
def my_bool(cadena):
    return cadena.lower() == "true"
```

Si lo prefieres puedes evitar definir tu propia función, y simplemente hacer:

```
x1 = sh['D60'].value.lower() == "true"
x2 = sh['D62'].value.lower() == "true"
```

pero yo creo que queda más organizado y legible así:

```
x1 = my_bool(sh["D60"])
x2 = my_bool(sh["D62"])
```

Además de evitar la repetición de código y ser más fácil de cambiar si por lo que sea resulta que tu excel pasa a usar "VERDADERO" en vez de "true".

Comment: Perfecto! muchas gracias. Magnifica explicación.

Comment: Enteros como 2 y -5 tambien devuelven True al ser evaluados con bool. 0 es el unico entero donde bool devuelve False.

Comment: @DanteS. Si, por supuesto. No sé en qué estaba pensando, ya lo he arreglado. Gracias!

Comment: De nada Abulafia! c: